# Join BigQuery tables in different projects using Service Accounts

Tags: google-bigquery, service-accounts

I have service accounts per BigQuery project. I need to put joins on tables in different projects using service accounts configured on each project.

Here is what i have:

1. Service_EmailAccount1 -> project1
2. Service_EmailAccount2 -> project2

I can connect to tables using these service accounts in respective projects but when I try to join data on different tables which are in different projects, I get access errors.

Reason is when i build the BigQuery service , I am using a JSON file which is specific to project as it contains the project id.

How can I join tables in different projects using service accounts?

Comment: show us your SQL, and your error message(s)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you run your query by Service_EmailAccount1
In this case you should just share your respective dataset in project2 with Service_EmailAccount1
And you must make sure both datasets are in the same location
That's all you need

See more about [Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/access-control) concept in BigQuery

Comment: While connecting using service account , i will need json. That json will be different for different projects or same json will help in connecting to datasets in different projects.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following idea might be helpful, for example, you are using service_emailaccount1 to get access of project1,

1. go to bigquery, click the project name, then choose -> switch project -> manage projects, you will go to IAm & Admin page
2. choose project1 and then you will see the permission page for the project.
3. add service_emalaccount2 to be a viewer/editor to this project1(if account1 is the owner)

Then, I believe that both accounts will access project1. 
 
This is what I will do to get access to several projects, and I am not sure we can use different service account to querying from different project in one query. Thx

Comment: i would not recommend using this approach as it opens all datasets in project1 to be viewed/edited for service_emalaccount2 . in my practice this is a big NO-NO!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thank you, that is right. Depends on what he need, he can choose to share datasets or the whole project.